# Write R data as csv directly to s3

Tags: r, csv, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like to be able to write data directly to a bucket in AWS s3 from a `data.frame`\ `data.table` object as a csv file without writing it to disk first using the AWS CLI.

```
obj.to.write.s3 <- data.frame(cbind(x1=rnorm(1e6),x2=rnorm(1e6,5,10),x3=rnorm(1e6,20,1)))
```

at the moment I write to csv first then upload to an existing bucket then remove the file using:

```
fn <- 'new-file-name.csv'
write.csv(obj.to.write.s3,file=fn)
system(paste0('aws s3 ',fn,' s3://my-bucket-name/',fn))
system(paste0('rm ',fn))
```

I would like a function that writes directly to s3? is that possible?

Answer (score 31):

In [aws.s3](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3) 0.2.2 the `s3write_using()` (and `s3read_using()`) functions were added.

They make things much simpler:

```
s3write_using(iris, FUN = write.csv,
                    bucket = "bucketname",
                    object = "objectname")
```

Comment: This is a nice one, you can also use this function in order to easily save parquet files- `s3write_using(iris, FUN = arrow::write_parquet, bucket = "bucketname", object = "objectname")`

Comment: what does the objectname refer to? The folder in the S3 bucket?

Comment: @nak5120 there isn't really such thing as a "folder" in s3 (look it up in Google), what you think is a folder is actually part of the name of the object, and you should provide it in  `objectname`

Comment: It's worth noting that using `s3write_using` does make things simpler, but also writes the file to your local disk before placing it in S3.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest solution is just to save the .csv in a `tempfile()`, which will be purged automatically when  you close your R session.

If you need to only work in memory you can do this by doing `write.csv()` to a rawConnection:

```
# write to an in-memory raw connection
zz <- rawConnection(raw(0), "r+")
write.csv(iris, zz)

# upload the object to S3
aws.s3::put_object(file = rawConnectionValue(zz),
    bucket = "bucketname", object = "iris.csv")

# close the connection
close(zz)
```

In case you're unsure, you can then check that this worked correctly by downloading the object from S3 and reading it back into R:

```
# check that it worked
## (option 1: save locally)
save_object(object = "iris.csv", bucket = "bucketname", file = "iris.csv")
read.csv("iris.csv")
## (option 2: keep in memory)
read.csv(text = rawToChar(get_object(object = "iris.csv", bucket = "bucketname")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure -- but 'saving to file' requires that your OS sees the desired target directory as an accessible filesystem.  So in essence you "just" need to mount S3. Here is a [quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=mount+S3+as+local&oq=mount+S3+as+local&aqs=chrome..69i57.3927j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8) for that topic.

An alternative is writing to a temporary file, and then using whatever you use to transfer files.  You could code up both operations as a simple helper function.